# Parse.com workflow explanation

Tags: parse-platform

After reading Parse.com's documentation, I have a few questions :

- If a user logs has a local score of 10 and a score of 30 on Parse's server (he played on a different phone), he logs in, plays, and scores 20. There is some "race" synchronization problem with the score of 30. How does Parse manage that ?
- I imagine that most people have the same device they use. So you want to save locally and update the backend, and at game start synchronize the local information with the backend and use the local info. What are the functions for that ? I see `pin`, `saveEventually` but I am a bit confused

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming as such, but about specific application features; you should probably contact the partse.com support staff.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker the second point asks for the 3 or 4 most used functions in Parse in a workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse can handle the increment for you, so you don't have to care about race condititions, see the `increment`-method. You are probably best off doing this in Cloud Code (using MasterKey) and lock down so that regular users can not update high score themselves.

I'm guessing you are working with Android? See this blog post about the Local Data Store; http://blog.parse.com/2014/04/30/take-your-app-offline-with-parse-local-datastore/